# Compile time error while initializing start object

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

I want to initialize a variable to the value of `nodes[_node]`, but it is giving an error.

I tried `start = &nodes[_node];` and it is not giving any error, but I don't want to initialize address I want to initialize value.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct  graph
{
    int data;
    struct graph *next;
};

struct graph *nodes =  new graph[5];

void connectnode(int _data,int _node)
{
    struct graph *start = nodes[_node];

    struct graph *temp = new  graph;

    temp ->data = _data;
    temp ->next = nullptr;

    if(start == nullptr)
        start->next = temp;
    else
    {
        while(start != nullptr)
            start = start->next;

        start->next = temp;
    }

}
```

The error is:

```
Compile time error - cannot convert 'graph' to 'graph*' in initialization
```

Comment: `nodes` is a `graph*`, so `nodes[_node]` is a `graph` and can't be assigned to `graph *start`. You probably wanted `struct graph *start = &nodes[_node];` instead.

Answer (score 0):

With `nodes[_node];` you are getting an element of the array `graph`, so you are getting a `graph` type . However you are assigning this element to a pointer of type `struct graph *start`.

So the line should be:

```
struct graph *start = &nodes[_node];
```

I don't understand why you don't want to do that but if so you can try:

```
struct graph start = nodes[_node];
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought nodes[_node] is a pointer type